# How to return HTTP status code when returning a ResourceCollection in Laravel

Tags: laravel, http, eloquent, httpresponse, http-status-codes

I'm building an API and I'm trying to return a ResourceCollection for a Classroom in Laravel.

Previously I used an array of classrooms and returned a response with the array and the status code, like this:

```
$classrooms=Classroom::all();
return response()->json($classrooms,200);
```

Now this is my code:

```
$classrooms = new ClassroomCollection(Classroom::paginate(10));
   return $classrooms;
```

to get this response:

```
"data": [classrooms array],
"links": {
        "first": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/classrooms ?page=1",
        "last": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/classrooms ?page=1",
        "prev": null,
        "next": null
         },
"meta": {
        "current_page": 1,
        "from": null,
        "last_page": 12,
        "path": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/classrooms ",
        "per_page": 10,
        "to": null,
        "total": 0
         }
```

and I can't find a way to send a status code along with the ClassroomCollection, because if I do

```
return response()->json($classrooms,200);
```

I'm only returned the "data" object, without the links and meta of the paginator.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

you can override the withResponse function in your collection like this:

```
public function withResponse($request, $response)
{
    if($response->getData()) {
        $response->setStatusCode(200);
    } else{
        $response->setStatusCode(404);
    }
    parent::withResponse($request, $response);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! it works! But what if I want to differentiate the response code? For exampe, if the list is empty I want to send a 404, otherwise a 200 OK

Comment: you can check response data if is null set status code to 404

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to you can do the following:

```php
return response()->json($classrooms->jsonSerialize(), 200);
```

*`->jsonSerialize()` does not actually serialize as a JSON string but returns an array that can be serialized to JSON string. Laravel serializes to a JSON response if you return an array or [`JsonSerializable`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php)able object from a controller/route and that is what the [paginator implements](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/104c539c342d395e2f3c4ba7339df095f83f6352/src/Illuminate/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.php#L14).*

However, if [200](https://httpstatuses.com/200) is the status code you want, that is implied and the default status code and there is no need to supply it.

So the above is equal to:

```php
return $classrooms;
```

Comment: What if I have to send a 404 instead? Should I use the first solution you provided?

Comment: Yes. But if you want to send a 404 you usually don't want to send the paginator response. And you can do something like `return response()->json(['error' => 'Classroom not found'], 404)`.

Comment: To clarify on that, when you return a collection from an API an empty result is not a 404 response. A 404 response would be needed when the route or resource (singular) doesn't exist, so when retrieving a single classroom for example. When returning an empty paginator of classrooms a 200 would be expected.

Comment: Yeah, I'm in a particular situation in which the customer wants to have the standard json with an additional "error" section, and I'd like to send a status code along with it. By the way, I tried the solution you proposed but I'm not getting anything in return, just "[]"

Comment: Oh, ok, so when I ask for an index of the classrooms, or any other object, I have to send a 200? 404 is only for the single resource?

Comment: You ofcourse don't have too, but empty indexes are not usually a 404. They just return an empty list since the resource/endpoint was found there is just nothing to show. A 404 would indicate the classrooms endpoint in your example doesn't exist at all (which it does, there are just no classrooms). Maybe the following page might help to shed some light on where and when to use what response codes: https://restfulapi.net/http-status-codes/

Comment: Thanks! That's really helpful

Comment: If the above doesn't clarify or answer your question you could edit your question to add what exactly you would want in the response so we can answer more targeted at what you would expect to return in the response.